# pylab not loading in emacs using ipython

Tags: python, emacs, matplotlib, scipy, ipython

I am using Emacs 24.3 in Windows 8. Using PowerShell, `ipython` loads `pylab` without issue:

```
PS C:\Users\vince.forgetta> ipython --pylab
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
Using matplotlib backend: TkAgg

In [1]: linspace
Out[1]: <function numpy.core.function_base.linspace>

In [2]: plot
Out[2]: <function matplotlib.pyplot.plot>
```

However, using Emacs 24.3 I get the following error:

```
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: 
In [2]: 
In [3]: 
In [4]: linspace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-fbab96054277> in <module>()
----> 1 linspace

NameError: name 'linspace' is not defined

In [5]: plot
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-88d627f14d84> in <module>()
----> 1 plot

NameError: name 'plot' is not defined
```

Which can be solved by importing pylab:

```
In [6]: from pylab import *

In [7]: linspace
Out[7]: <function numpy.core.function_base.linspace>
```

The Python specific code in my `.emacs` is:

```
;; Python
(setenv "PYTHONUNBUFFERED" "x")
; python-mode
(setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.1.3")
(add-to-list 'load-path py-install-directory)
(require 'python-mode)
; use IPython
(setq-default py-shell-name "ipython")
(setq-default py-which-bufname "IPython")
;; use the wx backend, for both mayavi and matplotlib
(setq py-python-command-args
  '("--gui=wx" "--pylab=wx" "--colors=Linux"))
(setq py-force-py-shell-name-p t)
; switch to the interpreter after executing code
(setq py-shell-switch-buffers-on-execute-p t)
(setq py-switch-buffers-on-execute-p t)
; don't split windows
(setq py-split-windows-on-execute-p nil)
; try to automagically figure out indentation
(setq py-smart-indentation t)
```

From this it would appear that `pylab` is being imported when `ipython` starts using the `--pylab` option, but clearly this doesn't seem to work as I anticipate, or there is an error somewhere. The buffer *Messages* does not report any errors.

How do I get `pylab` to load automatically when starting an `ipython` buffer?

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to partially track it down to 1) `--pylab=wx` option does not work, as the back-end is missing and 2) `--pylab=auto` works, but only when I load the .emacs file manually via `M-x load-file`.

Comment: `--pylab` is going to be deprecated.  Use `--matplotlib` to set up the gui-loop magic and then (if you must) do the bulk import.  The suggested import scheme is `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `import numpy as np`.